# CustomRenderMap on xamarin.forms.maps hides part of the content on the ListView

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I have one `CustomRenderMap` and one `ListView`. When I want to put the `Map` above and `ListView` under Map, the marker on the map cannot be clicked to display Listview.

When ListView is above and map is under listview. The bookmark can be clicked, but some of the content is hidden from the map.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MaritsaTundzhaForecast"
             x:Class="MaritsaTundzhaForecast.MainPage">

   <Grid>
       <StackLayout HeightRequest="1000">
           <ListView x:Name="lstLevel">
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ViewCell>
                                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <Label HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"
                                           Text="{Binding dateForecast}"
                                           Padding="10,0,0,0"/>
                                     <Label HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"
                                           Text="{Binding levelForecast}"
                                           Padding="10,0,0,0"/>
                                </StackLayout>
                            </ViewCell>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>
       </StackLayout>

   
        <Grid Margin="0,70,0,10" VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="250" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <StackLayout>
              <local:CustomMap x:Name="customMap"
                               MapType="Street"
                               HasZoomEnabled="True"
                               HasScrollEnabled="False"/>
          </StackLayout>
        </Grid>   
    </Grid>
</ContentPage>
```

My CustomMapRenderer class in android project is:

```
   using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Gms.Maps;
using Android.Gms.Maps.Model;
using Android.Widget;
using MaritsaTundzhaForecast;
using MaritsaTundzhaForecast.Models;
using MaritsaTundzhaForecast.Droid;
using MySqlConnector;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Maps;
using Xamarin.Forms.Maps.Android;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CustomMap), typeof(CustomMapRenderer))]
namespace MaritsaTundzhaForecast.Droid
{
    public class CustomMapRenderer : MapRenderer, GoogleMap.IInfoWindowAdapter
    {
        List<CustomPin> customPins;

        public CustomMapRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
        {
        }

        protected override void OnElementChanged(Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.ElementChangedEventArgs<Map> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (e.OldElement != null)
            {
                NativeMap.InfoWindowClick -= OnInfoWindowClick;
            }

            if (e.NewElement != null)
            {
                var formsMap = (CustomMap)e.NewElement;
                customPins = formsMap.CustomPins;
            }
        }

        protected override void OnMapReady(GoogleMap map)
        {
            base.OnMapReady(map);

            NativeMap.InfoWindowClick += OnInfoWindowClick;
            NativeMap.SetInfoWindowAdapter(this);
        }

        protected override MarkerOptions CreateMarker(Pin pin)
        {
            var marker = new MarkerOptions();
            marker.SetPosition(new LatLng(pin.Position.Latitude, pin.Position.Longitude));
            marker.SetTitle(pin.Label);
            marker.SetSnippet(pin.Address);
            //marker.SetIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.FromResource(Resource.Drawable.green));

            var custom = customPins.Where(x => x.Label == pin.Label && x.Address == pin.Address).FirstOrDefault();

            if (custom != null)
            {
                if (custom.AlertLevel == 1)
                {
                    marker.SetIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.FromResource(Resource.Drawable.green));
                }
                if (custom.AlertLevel == 2)
                {
                    marker.SetIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.FromResource(Resource.Drawable.yellow));
                }
                if (custom.AlertLevel == 3)
                {
                    marker.SetIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.FromResource(Resource.Drawable.orange));
                }
                if (custom.AlertLevel == 4)
                {
                    marker.SetIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.FromResource(Resource.Drawable.red));
                }
            }
            return marker;
        }

        void OnInfoWindowClick(object sender, GoogleMap.InfoWindowClickEventArgs e)
        {
            var customPin = GetCustomPin(e.Marker);
            if (customPin == null)
            {
                throw new Exception("Custom pin not found");
            }

            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(customPin.Url))
            {
                var url = Android.Net.Uri.Parse(customPin.Url);
                var intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionView, url);
                intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);
                Android.App.Application.Context.StartActivity(intent);
            }
        }

        public Android.Views.View GetInfoContents(Marker marker)
        {
            var inflater = Android.App.Application.Context.GetSystemService(Context.LayoutInflaterService) as Android.Views.LayoutInflater;
            if (inflater != null)
            {
                Android.Views.View view;

                var customPin = GetCustomPin(marker);
                if (customPin == null)
                {
                    throw new Exception("Custom pin not found");
                }

                if (customPin.Name.Equals("Xamarin"))
                {
                    view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.XamarinMapInfoWindow, null);
                }
                else
                {
                    view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.MapInfoWindow, null);
                }

                CustomPin pin = GetCustomPin(marker);

                int CodeNum = pin.CodeNum;
                int AlertLevel = pin.AlertLevel;

                var infoTitle = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.InfoWindowTitle);
                var infoSubtitle = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.InfoWindowSubtitle);
                var infoSubtitle2 = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.InfoWindowSubtitle2);
                var infoSubtitle3 = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.InfoWindowSubtitle3);

                if (infoTitle != null)
                {
                    infoTitle.Text = marker.Title;
                }
                if (infoSubtitle != null)
                {
                    infoSubtitle.Text = marker.Snippet;
                }
                if (infoSubtitle2 != null)
                {
                    infoSubtitle2.Text = "Тревога: (1-4): " + AlertLevel;
                }
                if (infoSubtitle3 != null)
                {
                    infoSubtitle3.Text = "Код на станция: " + CodeNum;
                }

                return view;
            }
            return null;
        }

        public Android.Views.View GetInfoWindow(Marker marker)
        {
            return null;
        }

        public IEnumerable<AlertLevel> DataBaseConnection(int mapCode)
        {
            string ConnectionString = "server=192.168.0.1;uid=user;port=3387;pwd=password;database=dbname;";
            MySqlConnection Conn = new MySqlConnection(ConnectionString);
            var listAlert = new List<AlertLevel>();

            try
            {
                Conn.Open();

                //replace(2) with mapCode
                string query = "CALL Get_Alert_levels_Station(" + mapCode + ");";
                MySqlCommand myCommand = new MySqlCommand(query, Conn);
                MySqlDataReader myReader;

                myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();

                try
                {
                    while (myReader.Read())
                    {
                        var currentData = new AlertLevel()
                        {
                            
                            dateForecast = myReader.GetDateTime(0),
                            levelForecast = myReader.GetInt32(1)
                            
                        };

                        listAlert.Add(currentData);
                    } 
                }
                finally
                {
                    myReader.Close();
                    Conn.Close();
                }
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Database Connection", "Not Connected ..." + Environment.NewLine + ex.ToString(), "OK");
            }

            return listAlert;
        }

        CustomPin GetCustomPin(Marker annotation)
        {
            string id = annotation.Id.Substring(1);

            int mapCode = int.Parse(id);

            var result = DataBaseConnection(mapCode);

            MessagingCenter.Send<object, IEnumerable<AlertLevel>>(this, "PinSelected", result);

            var position = new Position(annotation.Position.Latitude, annotation.Position.Longitude);

            foreach (var pin in customPins)
            {
                if (pin.Position == position)
                {
                    return pin;
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

How to arrange so that the map is on top and listview to be under the map so click the marker ?

Comment: your outer grid has now rows defined so all of it's children will occupy the same cell.  Logically if A is on top of B in the Z-Order, then you will not be able to interact with items in B.

Comment: Can you give some example on which grid to set rol ?

Comment: "your outer grid"

Comment: Grid.Row=0 on outer grid, and grid.row=1 on other ?

Comment: No.  The **outer grid** contains two children, a StackLayout and another Grid.  Both of these children appear to be in the same row (you didn't include a screenshot so I can't say for sure).  You need to place the **children** in two different rows

Comment: I understand, I fix it ! Thank you